# JSP call javascript function through href

Tags: javascript, jsp

The following code in JSP:

```
while(rs2.next()) 
    { 
        out.println(rs2.getString(1));
        %>
            <a href="javascript:displayData(<%=rs2.getString(1)%>)">Run The App</a>
        <%
        out.println("<br>");
    }
```

I want for each element to print its name and a link to JavaScript function that takes the name as a parameter.

The JavaScript that I have is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function displayData(ctr) {
        alert(ctr);
        <%
            Process p = null;
            Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime(); 
            String command; 
            File dir = new File("C:/app/webapps/data"); 
            command="javaw -jar "+ctr;
            try 
            { 
                p = r.exec(command,null,dir);
            }
            catch(Exception e) 
            { } 
        %>
    }
</script>
```

What the function does is to execute a jar file (the jar file is executed by calling its name which in this case the parameter that I pass `ctr`). The error that I got is:

```
ctr cannot be resolved to a varialbe
```

Can someone help me in this problem?

Comment: If I understood correctly, you can not mix java and Javascript this way. What kind of applications do you working on? If this is an Web applications you can not run jar from Javascript.

Comment: Try `<a href="javascript:displayData('<%=rs2.getString(1)%>')">Run The App</a>` add `'` in parameter

Comment: @CyberAleks the problem is how to pass Javascript parameter (`ctr`) to JSP. In other words, pass from client to server.

Comment: :) as I said, you can not do it this way. You should call some url to pass some parameter to jsp. If you want to it in background (without refreshing), you should use Ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to call Jsp from client is to call an url. If you want to do this asynchronously (without refreshing) you should use Ajax. I think you are looking for something like this https://blog.udemy.com/jsp-ajax/.